# To use OULAD datasets how do I join or merge them?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am using [OULAD dataset](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata2017171#usage-notes) It has 7 csv file which are linked together in the way shown in the image in the OULAD website.

one of the csv files named student_registration has 32593 rows and 5 columns and another one named student_Vle has  10655280 rows and 6 columns.

I want to add  columns date & sum_click from student_vle to student_registration table such that only existing 32593 students information is added.

I tried left join but the result is very weird. It has [13009427 rows x 11 columns] instead of 32593 rows and 8 columns. Its like Union.

U can get the dataset from UCI repository.

here is my code-

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    student_reg = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/studentRegistration.csv')
    student_vle = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/studentVle.csv')

    student_reg_vle = pd.merge(student_reg, student_vle, on='id_student', how='left')
    student_reg_vle.set_index('id_student', inplace=True)
    print(student_reg_vle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with duplicated data, need unique rows, so solution is remove dupes:

```
student_vle = student_vle.drop_duplicates('id_student')
```

Comment: after running the command  still there are 13009427 rows and 11 columns. But in result I want 8 columns (code_module ,code_presentation , id_student , date_registration , date_unregistration, id_site, date , sum_click).  What should I do ?